# Show "curtain" when Screen Sharing?

Tags: screen-sharing

***EDIT: My request is to know whether or not Screen Sharing supports this feature still in anyway. I'm aware that other solutions do, but am not interested in other solutions for this question. Thanks!***

Screen Sharing used to support showing a "curtain" when connected to a remote machine, so people at the same location as the remote machine couldn't interact with the machine in anyway. I don't know if this feature was very publicly available or not, but it could be enabled by editing a plist in the past.

Can this still be enabled in anyway?

I know that Apple Remote Desktop supports this feature as well, but I'd prefer to use Screen Sharing if possible, since it's free, and well supported in every other way.

Note: I'm aware that if another user is logged in, then when I connect with Screen Sharing, it will give me the option to not take control of the main screen, which is ok, but requires our users to remember to login as another fake user before leaving, which is hard to remember all the time

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to use screen sharing without the remote screen being visible?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/241745/is-it-possible-to-use-screen-sharing-without-the-remote-screen-being-visible)

Comment: I think this needs to be enabled by the client? I use the iPhone app Remotix to login to my Mac (no special software on the Mac side, just native Screen Sharing), and it has a "lock remote screen" option which works.