# How to trigger Curtain Mode in a macOS host from a non-macOS guest?

Tags: remote-desktop

In the past, it was possible to raise Curtain Mode on a macOS host from a non-macOS guest, such as a Linux guest, by invoking `LockScreen.app` in the native Apple VNC server to hide the contents of the remote session (as described by Jamf users [here](https://community.jamf.com/t5/jamf-pro/locking-down-jamfhelper-lockscreen/m-p/95958)). However, this no longer appears to work on newer releases of macOS; calling the app over ssh does not activate Curtain Mode. In fact, it appears to do nothing. Apple Remote Desktop can raise Curtain Mode, but it is only available for macOS guests.

Is it possible to raise the native Curtain Mode on macOS (Ventura) from a non-macOS guest (e.g., Ubuntu 22.04)? An ssh-based solution would presumably work, but there doesn't seem to be a way to call `LockScreen.app` without having the proprietary Apple Remote Desktop installed.

This question is somewhat similar to [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/241745/is-it-possible-to-use-screen-sharing-without-the-remote-screen-being-visible) but with a more specific use case (raising the native Curtain Mode function rather than installing a third-party application, such as TeamViewer). Additionally, many of the solutions and details no longer apply to modern macOS versions.